# Using struct to update values

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I'm stuck when I'm updating an empty string values in a struct for updating dynamodb table.

Currently I have this struct

```
type Client struct {
    ClientID       *string    `json:"client_key,omitempty"`
    Name           *string    `json:"client_name,omitempty"`
    Address        *string    `json:"address,omitempty"`
    Country        *string    `json:"country,omitempty"`
    City           *string    `json:"city,omitempty"`
    State          *string    `json:"state,omitempty"`
    PostCode       *string    `json:"post_code,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt      *time.Time `json:"created_at,omitempty"`
}
```

And this code when updating an item

```
keyAttr, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(key)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
valAttr, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(attributes)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

`keyAttr` will be used for the `Key` field and `valAttr` will be used in `ExpressionAttributeValues` field. Note that I didn't include the complete updating fields function to save space. But I will do that if you ask for it.

Currently the function is running fine except when I updated one of the field with empty string. E.g. `client.Address = aws.String("")`. While I'm fine with dynamodb converting my empty string to `null`, I can't seem to find a way to update it because of the `omitempty` tag.

I need the omitempty tag to ignore all `nil` values. However, I just researched that the `omitempty` tag also omits empty string values. Currently I have to make a struct in my function like this.

```
type client struct {
    Name     *string `json:"client_name"`
    Address  *string `json:"address"`
    Country  *string `json:"country"`
    City     *string `json:"city"`
    State    *string `json:"state"`
    PostCode *string `json:"post_code"`
}
```

But i'm not a fan of repeating things. So, the question is: is there any better way of doing this? How do you guys use structs with dynamodb?

**EDIT**

Based on @Peter's comment, it seems that `json.Encode()` does print the empty string if it's not nil.

`{"client_key":"test","username":"test","email":"","first_name":"test","last_name":"","phone":"","title":"","email_verified":false,"phone_verified":false,"updated_at":"2018-12-06T14:04:56.2743841+11:00"}`

The problem seems to be in `dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap` function

Comment: omitempty on a string pointer doesn't omit pointers to an empty string: https://play.golang.org/p/D4ijz4aVLok Any non-nil pointer isn't empty as far the JSON package is concerned.

Comment: hmmm that's weird! I can't seem to update the dynamodb when I use `omitempty` on the struct. Maybe it's because of `dynamodbattribute`? I'll take a look!

Comment: hmmm the problem seems to be dynamodb does not allow empty string and it converts it to null. But because of omitempty, null values are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trials, I finally got it. I didn't test it so I don't know whether it's buggy or not. But it seems to work for me right now.

So what I did was encode the struct with `json.Marshal` first then use `json.Unmarshal` with a `map[string]interface{}`. Then, I use `dynamodbattribute.Marshal` to convert it to `map[string]*AttributeValue`

Here's the code:

```
var temp map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal(tempStr, &temp)
valAttr, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(temp)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```